# How to save and restore HTMLCanvasElement from localStorage or JSON file

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, local-storage

I have an array of created `canvas` elements acting as snapshots of a `video`, then I draw the `canvas` frames directly onto a main `canvas` that is attached to the `DOM` (as it is faster for performance than converting the canvases to a `dataURL` or `Image` first).

My challenge is when I try to save the canvases array to `localStorage` for faster access on repeat loads, the canvas elements `stringify` and `parse` to be empty objects.

What's the best way to go about this?

```js
arrayOfCanvasElements = [];
storeVideoFramesAsCanvas() {
    const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.drawImage(myVideo, 0, 0);
    arrayOfCanvasElements.push(canvas);
}
drawCanvasElementOnMainCanvas(arrayOfCanvasElements[0])
```

Is there a better storage for storing elements than localStorage as I would love to be able to keep my canvas data as an `HTMLCanvasElement`

```
arrayOfCanvasElements => [ canvas, canvas, canvas... ]
// Stringify for localStorage
JSON.stringify(arrayOfCanv) => [ {}, {}, {}... ]
```

Can I store to a JSON/text file and get correct array on load? The process for getting all the canvas element frames take a while and would love a json file or something I could load without having to actually reconvert the video to frames every time the page loads.

Comment: Others will dislike your question like this. please provide a minimal executable code and read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) about how to ask a good question.

Comment: Updated with snippets @Mad7Dragon

Comment: @ladiri8539 You mistakenly expect the script host to do the right thing and *serialize* your array of canvases into something that can be both written to storage and later restorable from said storage. The problem is that your assumption is wrong -- an array of canvases serializes in a manner where each canvas must be serialized and `Canvas` serializes by calling its `toString` method which trivially returns something like `"[object Canvas]"`. The pixel data is thus missing. You may not even be able to fitt all of the pixels in local storage, either, even if you stored them as an array.

Comment: Does that mean the best outcome would be to serialize and save the video frames as `dataURL` and then load, convert to image and draw on main `canvas` even though it will be slightly slower than drawing a `HTMLCanvasElement`
@ArmenMichaeli

Comment: It depends on whether and how much speed or size you want to sacrifice and your requirements. If the canvas(es) are large enough, forget about storing these with `localStorage` at least -- that's absolutely the _wrong_ place to store these. Look at [IndexedDb](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) or, I don't know, consider not storing them? What application are you making that needs storage on user's computer? Second, if your drawing can be reproduced, store the drawing instead -- more compact. Third, convert to PNG and store those as they're smaller than a bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

What you are using from your `<canvas>` elements is actually their *bitmap* data. Instead of using that many `<canvas>` elements, you'd be better creating [`ImageBitmap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/createImageBitmap) objects that do store the same *bitmap* data as `<canvas>` objects, but without a lot of stuff that come with the `<canvas>`.

But `ImageBitmap` objects can't really be stored in the browser's storage either. To store *bitmap* data, we generally create image files, which thanks to their compression algorithms will make a good job of shrinking the data needed to represent the *bitmap* data without losing too much info (or not at all if using lossless formats).
You can create such an image file by first [rendering the `ImageBitmap` object on a canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageBitmapRenderingContext/transferFromImageBitmap) and then calling its [`toBlob()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toBlob) method.
The `Blob` object you receive in the callback to `toBlob()` can then be saved in the browser's [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API).
At next page load, you'll be able to retrieve all these saved `Blob` objects and create new `ImageBitmap` objects from them directly.

If you're not yet familiar with `IndexedDB`, then I can only recommend the use of Mozilla's [*localForage* library](https://github.com/localForage/localForage), which helps a lot working with it.